# Project RGB with Switches

Tags: c, algorithm, performance

I am working on project in which I need to display different colors
on RGB led. I am using pwm to drive different colors on LED. My Pic
is PIC24FJ64GA004 with which I am working on now. Basic concept of
this project is to use switch to controls colors.

Colors on RGB led will be according to days and month in year. For
that I am using 7-segment led with switch to count days and month.

Problem is that I have only one switch on my board. I have designed
hardware and bits for it has been tested as well. So hardware works
fine.

At the moment my problem is pic code.

I am stuck in switch use now. I have one switch on board. I need to
display how many times switch pressed on 7 segment. Problem is that
I am new to Pic code and confuse as well. First switch status will be checked. If switch pressed for two seconds it will go days mode. otherwise it will stick to months mode.It will display month or days according to that.I have pasted my code here please give
me some positive advice.

I would like to know is this coding is going in right way or not.

```
void switch_function(void)
{
    if (PORTAbits.RA4==1)               // is SW1 pressed?
    {                            
        IEC0bits.T1IE       = 1;        // Enable Output Compare interrupts
           T1CONbits.TON        = 1;        // Start Timer1 with assumed settings   
        if (modecounter==0)                 // Checking status of month  
        {
            if (PORTAbits.RA4==1) 
            {    
                counter++;
                if (counter== 12)
                {   
                    counter = 0;
                } 
            }
        } 
        else if(modecounter ==1)            // Checking status of days
        {
            if (PORTAbits.RA4==1)
            { 
                counter++;
                if (counter== 32)
                {  
                    counter = 0 ;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }     
    }
    else
    {
        counter =0;
    }
    return ;
}

  //***** Timer1 interrupt *****//

void __attribute__((interrupt, auto_psv)) _T1Interrupt(void)
{ 
    timer_counter++;

    if (timer_counter== 2)
    {
        if (PORTAbits.RA4==1) 
        {  // is SW1 still has pressed status after 2sec delay?
            modecounter = 1;         // switch to days 
        }
        else
        {
            modecounter = 0;  // switch to months
        }          
    }
    else
    {
    }
    IFS0bits.T1IF=0; /* clear timer1 interrupt flag */      
    return;
} 

//***** Timer2 interrupt *****//

void __attribute__ ((__interrupt__, no_auto_psv)) _T2Interrupt(void)
{
    IFS0bits.T2IF = 0; /* clear timer2 interrupt flag */    
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately, we only focus on already working code (see the [faq](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq)), so your question is off-topic. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Post it on http://stackoverflow.com/ with tags c embedded pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

1. Why check this twice `PORTAbits.RA4==1` in the same if-block?
2. Following can be rewritten:

   ```
   counter++;
   if (counter== 12)
   {   
       counter = 0;
   }
   ```

   to:

   ```
   if(++counter == 12)
   {
       counter = 0;
   }
   ```

   or:

   ```
   counter = (++counter == 12) ? 0 : counter;
   ```
3. Same here

   ```
   if (PORTAbits.RA4==1) 
   {  // is SW1 still has pressed status after 2sec delay?
       modecounter = 1;         // switch to days 
   }
   else
   {
       modecounter = 0;  // switch to months
   }
   ```

   to:

   ```
   modecounter = (PORTAbits.RA4==1) ? 1 : 0;
   ```

Comment: I am using switch twice because I want to switch counter from month to days.

Comment: First It will add month and then will add days. In order to switch to days. Need to press switch for 2 seconds.